# Possible to leave out ID[] from url?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have alot of data, that i can check, useing checkbox. when I 'Submit', and want to see all the data i checked, i get redirected to the result page. But lets say i choose to only check 1 element the URL is: http://XXX.xxx/Test/TestResults?ID%5B%5D=2728
this is okay, but lets say i choose to see 10 elements the URL is LONG: 
http://XXX.xxx/Test/TestResults?ID%5B%5D=2728&ID%5B%5D=2726&ID%5B%5D=2727&ID%5B%5D=2725&ID%5B%5D=2724&ID%5B%5D=2723&ID%5B%5D=2722&ID%5B%5D=2721&ID%5B%5D=2720&ID%5B%5D=2719

and the problem is that if i choose to see 100 elements, the URL will become so long that the site can alert me with: 'Submitted URI too large!'

is there any way only to show the id number, and not the ID[] (ID%5B%5D)?

The ID[] is the ID%5B%5D part, and then the id number will be added to it.

```py
echo "<input type = 'checkbox' name = 'ID[]' class = 'checkbox' value = '".$testjobids[$count]."'/>";

/*this is in another .php file where i get the ID*/
$SelectedTestjobids = $_GET['ID'];
```

**Link is shorter**

After useing _POST, i got this: http://XXX.xxx/Test/TestResults

*Problem*

The only problem i have now is that i can't link this site to anyone, because there isn't attached anything else but the site in the URL. Is there a way to make a uniqe number after the  http://XXX.xxx/Test/TestResults, so it's possible to share the link and it stills shows the same data?

Comment: Maybe use POST and not GET?

Comment: use `post` instead of `get` so you will be able to pass all data you need.

Comment: how would the backend know what it is if you do not include the ID[] ?

Comment: If they are guaranteed to be in range, use `fromID` and `toID`

Comment: Like the other suggested, use POST method instead of GET, so that the values will be sent in the request body instead of as a querystring and there will be no limits whatsoever.

Comment: Okay now with a _POST the URL is:  http://XXX.xxx/Test/TestResults
but the only problem now is that i cant link this page to another person or so, because the URL always is the same. Is there a way to make a uniqe URL or somthing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use a post request for some reason, you could copy the values you want and submit them as a more compact string, either manually or by adding the string to another form element before submitting.

Of course, your server code would have to know what to do with the comma-separated string when it receives it.

This example uses a hidden `<textarea>` element to hold the values:

```js
// Identifies HTML elements
const
  boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box"),
  area1 = document.getElementById("area1"),
  btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1"),
  div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

// Calls `submitCheckboxValuesAsText` when the button is clicked
btn1.addEventListener("click", submitCheckboxValuesAsText);

// Defines `submitCheckboxValuesAsText`
function submitCheckboxValuesAsText(){

  // Puts checked values in the textarea
  updateTextarea();

  // Copies the text from the textarea
  const text = area1.value;

  // Clears the demo div
  div1.innerHTML = "";

  // Formats the copied text within the demo div
  if(text){
    div1.innerHTML = "Imagine this gets sent to your server:<br /><br />" + 
      "<span class='grey'>" + text + "</span>";
  }    
}

// Defines `updateTextarea`
function updateTextarea(){

  area1.value = [...boxes] // `[...boxes]` converts `boxes` to a proper Array
    .filter(box => box.checked) // Makes a new Array of just the checked boxes
    .map(box => box.value) // Makes a new Array with the values of those boxes 
    .join(","); // Makes a string from the array, separated by commas
}
```

```css
label{ margin-right: 15px; }
#btn1{ margin: 20px 5px; }
.grey{ background-color: #DDDDDD; padding: 2px 5px; }
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="box" value="val1" /><span>box1</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="box" value="val2" /><span>box2</span></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="box" value="val3" /><span>box3</span></label>

<textarea id="area1" hidden></textarea>

<div><button id="btn1">Submit</button></div>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

(If you wanted to avoid submitting manually, you should probably populate the hidden field before the user clicks `Submit`, such as by using `document.addEventListener("change", updateTextarea);`.
You would also want to change the button to `<input type="submit" />`.)